# SQL Server 2008 files size in log folder keeps on increasing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logfile

Why doe the files in my log file for SQL Server 2008 keep on increasing. Even after I delete them, it will keep on creating new files.

The path for the files are as below:

C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER/MSSQL/Log

[image: File]

Above are the files available in the log folder, and the files size will keep on increasing until it takes up my hard disk space. Is there any setting that can help the files stop increasing its size?

Comment: Those aren't log files, they're memory dumps created when a process crashes.

Comment: @alroc my mistake as I'm not really familiar with these. Is there anything I can do to stop the memory dumps being created?

Comment: first of all, you should find why the server crashes, and try to fix that. the memory dump, i believe you can remove it just fine, but before removing them you can use [windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) to inspect and try to guess what is the cause. you cant stop the dump as they are automagically created whenever a crash happens. even windows keeps some on its Windows folder.